# Should I be testing results or behaviors?

Tags: python, testing

I'm trying to reduce the monolithicness of my code to make it into smaller/easier digestible units, but I'm not sure what the best practices are with testing. Here is an example:

```
def a(some_input):
...

def b(other_input):
    # Bunch of logic, possible other function calls
    if some_condition:
        a(...)
```

Testing `a` seems straightforward to me, but when it comes to `b`, should I be testing that when `b` is called with input that leads to it calling `a` calls `a` (in python that's something like a `Mock.assert_called_with`, or should I just be testing that the output is correct?

My view on this is let's say re-use `a` all over and break `a`; I think that's a bunch of false positive test failures since the surrounding logic/behavior is correct, and simply `a` should be fixed.

Comment: Depends on how complicated A is and whether A has dependencies.

Comment: Is there something else you can test about `b`, or is the side effect of calling `a` the only testable outcome?

Comment: There are other things b does, and I have cases for that! I guess I just don’t know what to do about calling a part of the code

Comment: @deetsb There's no one size-fits-all answer, we need more specifics about A and B. For example, does A call an external resource like an API? Or does A just do some internal calculation?

Comment: That’s a good question! A coworker brought it up too. In this simple case a is a quick calculation, so I guess it shouldn’t introduce instability or concerns if it is called in b’s test; but I imagine this is different if a was more strenuous

Comment: I prefer to test the result, but this is not always possible, sometimes you want to ensure that some side effect happened and you do this assuming that some function F yields that side effect and the unit being tested called F. This is for example the case when you're testing that something is saved in a database, without running a database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test documented outputs and side effects.

For example, if A is just making a sub-calculation which contributes to the output of B, unit tests of B should ignore it. A is an [internal implementation detail and can change at any time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-box_testing), B might even stop calling A; if the implementation changes the test breaks. [Only the documented return value of B should be tested](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White-box_testing). `assert_eq(b(10), 5)` or whatever.

Let's say A is a thing which sends an email. That is a documented side effect of calling B which should be tested. Rather than set up a fake mail server and all that, you would mock the call to A and test that B passed in the correct values. A would be unit tested separately. If A is complicated enough you might [split A out into a separate object](https://refactoring.guru/extract-class) which just sends email and have B use an instance of A.

In well-factored code, each subsystem is managed by their own object. Let's say B is totaling up the price of a sale, and A is doing complex tax calculations. A should be its own object which just does tax calculations, unit test A. When unit testing B, B doesn't really care what A returns, so long as the tax is included. The unit tests for B can mock A to return a fixed value and test the tax value from A is included in the result of B. With A and B thoroughly unit tested, you can do a simple integration test which calls B and the real A.